# Spark Shell connection to HDFS Protected with Kerberors

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, kerberos

I am trying to get a simple sc.textFile("hdfs://users/hadoop-user/hello-file.csv") to read data from a kerberos protected remote HDFS cluster.

Kerberos is properly configured on my local machine as well as on the remote hadoop cluster. I am able to test this by doing:

```
kinit hadoop-user@company-name.com
```

After doing this, I can use hdfs command line tool: hdfs dfs -ls /user.
I can also use pig to read from hdfs.

```
HADOOP_HOME is set in ~/bashrc file.
```

I tried different things with spark to no avail:

```
val text=sc.textFile("hdfs://users/hadoop-user/hello-file.csv")
val text=sc.textFile("/users/hadoop-user/hello-file.csv")
val text=sc.textFile("hdfs://namenode1.hadoop.mycompanie.com/users/hadoop-user/hello-file.csv")
```

Each of these commands is followed by text.count().

The first command produces:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: user
```

The second command produces:

```
InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist
```

The last command produces:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
```

How do I tell spark to use kerberos to authenticate to hdfs?

Comment: Can you check something first? Can you take a look in the folder `/etc/spark/conf/` check if there is a kerberos file called spark.keytab or anything like that.

Comment: Have you read http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#yarn-mode? How do you run `spark-shell`? Do you use `--principal` or `--keytab`?